# Apache - authorising a user in multiple groups

Tags: apache

I'm trying to work out how to check if a user is a member of Group A and Group B with basic authorisation in Apache. Currently I have:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Log Authors"
AuthUserFile /iweb/s3078033/apache2-secure/auth/user.file
AuthGroupFile /iweb/s3078033/apache2-secure/auth/group.file
Require group admin logger
```

which only checks if the user is a member of admin OR logger. I've tried looking all through the Apache documentation, but am not having much luck.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This should work [<RequireAll>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireall)

Compatibility:  Available in Apache 2.3 and later
Requires mod_authz_core

PS: I didn't try as I've only Apache 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

You've likely already tried but would placing the Require directive on two lines help?

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Log Authors"
AuthUserFile /iweb/s3078033/apache2-secure/auth/user.file
AuthGroupFile /iweb/s3078033/apache2-secure/auth/group.file
Require group admin
Require group logger
```

Comment: yeah, tried that ... no luck. I've tried looking to see if I need a mod, but not dice.